# Objective-C parsing Json and check if the response is a single object of an array of objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

I read one json file from the internet. It contains one or more sources. With my code if the user has got only one source the app crashes

```
NSDictionary *results = [stringSubscriptions JSONValue];

for (NSDictionary *element in results){
    SubscriptionArray *add = [[SubscriptionArray alloc] init];
    add.title=[element objectForKey:@"title"];
    add.source=[element objectForKey:@"website"];
    add.htmlUrl=[element objectForKey:@"id"];
    add.count=0;
    [onlySubsriptions addObject:add];
    [add release];

}
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Two or more objects

```
[
    {
        "website": "http://www.ispazio.net", 
        "updated": 1392645040345, 
        "title": "iSpazio - IL Blog Italiano per le Notizie sull'iPhone 5S, iPhone 5C, 5 e 4S con recensioni App Store e Guide al Jailbreak", 
        "topics": [
            "Apple", 
            "iphone", 
            "Tecnologia", 
            "Tech", 
            "Mac"
        ], 
        "sortid": "26152F8F", 
        "velocity": 196.0, 
        "id": "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/Ispazio", 
        "categories": []
    }, 
    {
        "website": "http://www.xataka.com", 
        "updated": 1392640863251, 
        "title": "Xataka", 
        "topics": [
            "TecnologÃ­a", 
            "Tecnologia", 
            "Gadgets", 
            "Tech"
        ], 
        "velocity": 92.200000000000003, 
        "id": "feed/http://feeds.weblogssl.com/xataka2", 
        "categories": []
    }
]
```

One Object

```
{
    "website": "http://www.ispazio.net", 
    "updated": 1392645040345, 
    "title": "iSpazio - IL Blog Italiano per le Notizie sull'iPhone 5S, iPhone 5C, 5 e 4S con recensioni App Store e Guide al Jailbreak", 
    "topics": [
        "Apple", 
        "iphone", 
        "Tecnologia", 
        "Tech", 
        "Mac"
    ], 
    "sortid": "26152F8F", 
    "velocity": 196.0, 
    "id": "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/Ispazio", 
    "categories": []
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check what kind of class is the result object, try something like that:

```
id result = [stringSubscriptions JSONValue];
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class])
    NSLog(@"NSArray");
else if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class])
    NSLog(@"NSDictionary");
```

Comment: And a handy little trick, to avoid the need for a lot of conditional statements to handle both:  If it's a single object (dictionary), insert it into an array and pass the array along as if it came from the other end.